# How to save NSDictionary to CoreData using NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, json, core-data, dictionary

I have a huge NSDictionary, having three levels hierarchy.

It looks hierarchy as below

1. A main JSON contains a Object  {}
2. It has few values on root, like and than an array, which has dictionary and that dictionary has also a dictionary.

   ```
   {

    "id" = "123",
   "name" = "Hello",
   "title_image" = "URL"

    "sub_array" : [
      {
       "id" = "123",
       "name" = "Hello",
       "title_image" = "URL"
        "another_dictionary":{
          "abc":{

           },
           "abcd":{

            }
         }
      },
      {
       "id" = "123",
       "name" = "Hello",
       "title_image" = "URL"
         "another_dictionary":{
          "abc":{

           },
           "abcd":{

            }
         }
       }
    ]

    }
   ```

Now I am confused, whether I should go for making separate NSManagedObject,  or make ONE NSManagedObject and make some relationships with other tables, or any other appraoch.

Can one tell me what should I do when I have huge NSDictionary(JSON from Server, which is converted to NSDictionary) and I want to save this in Core Data.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any offline support in your app ?

Comment: Yes, Its a offline support.  and Happy to see you here leena, How are Nitin and other guys in chat room of stack ? :)  @Leena

Comment: Have a look at RestKit which works with offline support and core data

Comment: I'm doing the same thing in a project where the JSON response from server always have the keys "code", "message", and "data". The object for key "data" in the JSON is a dictionary and it contains all the stuff I need. I'm also using core data to save the JSON response in iOS usable format. My suggestion is to create separate `NSManagedObjects` for the `subArrays` and `dictionaries` within the dictionary and use relationships to store those objects.

Comment: @Leena, nO, yet I didn't check RestKit. Let me browse it.l

Comment: @AdeelMiraj, I have discussed your idea in my question also. But I think, there would be more easy way, which could MAP and we would save time in managing relation, reverse etc.

Comment: I have same problem to store nsdictionary of json in coredata and fetch, if you have answer this, than upload i will upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
id delegate_info = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context_info = [delegate_info managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *ManagedObject_info = [NSEntityDescription
                                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@“localDBname” inManagedObjectContext:context_info];

[ManagedObject_info setValue:[[yourDictName valueForKey:@“key1”] valueForKey:@"user_email"] forKey:@“localdbkey1”];
[ManagedObject_info setValue:[yourDictName valueForKey:@“key2”] forKey:@"localdbkey2”];
[ManagedObject_info setValue:[yourDictName valueForKey:@“key3”] forKey:@"localdbkey3”];


NSError *error;
[context_info save:&error];
```

Note: If a value is an array or dictionary it will not work and crash when running.Because you defined that local db key as nsstring.

Comment: The upper code is a sample to save a dictionary into core data. But if you want to save your entire json as dictionary then define your core data attribute as transformable. It worked for me. i had a same problem while saving an array or dictionary into core data.